# Weka from command line Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, classpath, weka, cp

I usually use Weka from command line on Linux systems to perform feature selection on attributes as:

```
 java -cp PATH_TO_WEKA_JAR weka.attributeSelection.CfsSubsetEval ... (other parameters)
```

I'm trying to run the same code on Mac OS but I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka.attributeSelection.CfsSubsetEval
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.attributeSelection.CfsSubsetEval
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

How can I run the same command on Mac OS? Shouldn't be the same as it's a UNIX based OS?
I also tried to include the path within `" "` but there is no difference. What's is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is something wrong with the Weka jar file. It tells you it can't find a particular class in the file.

Mac OS has evolved away from Unix quite a bit, which may make it necessary to use a differend JAR file.

This may help you: Weka Site download

Comment: Well, that's the entire point. Mac OS has evolved away from Unix quite a bit, which may make it necessary to use a differend JAR file.

This may help you: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
jar tf PATH_TO_WEKA_JAR | grep weka.attributeSelection.CfsSubsetEval
```

In the output you should see a line with `weka.attributeSelection.CfsSubsetEval.class`.
If you don't see such line, then the `jar` file doesn't contain that class,
and the command cannot work.
In that case, try to run this:

```
jar tf PATH_TO_WEKA_JAR | less
```

to just see what is in the jar file.

One way or another, this is a simple class path issue:
the class `weka.attributeSelection.CfsSubsetEval` is simply not on your classpath.
You need to find the correct path to the jar,
possible to other dependencies as well,
and construct the correct parameter to use in:

```
java -cp CORRECT_CLASSPATH weka.attributeSelection.CfsSubsetEval   # ... your other params
```